# Performance of FileUtils.write from Apache Commons - Java

Tags: java, apache-commons

I have gone through the javadoc but I could't find anything.Does it buffer data internally?
If yes, since there is no close/flush operation, how does it make sure all data has been written. If it does not buffer, Does it go to disk everytime call is made?

[http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#write(java.io.File, java.lang.CharSequence, java.nio.charset.Charset, boolean)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#write%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.nio.charset.Charset,%20boolean%29)

I looked at source code here, http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.java#FileUtils.openOutputStream%28java.io.File%2Cboolean%29 and it does not seem to do any buffering. It opens a stream every time.

Comment: Sure it has a close/flush operation; it just does it itself, rather than making you do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From looking at the source, a new stream is created, the data is written out, and then the stream is closed.

[Here's the link to the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.3/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.java#FileUtils.writeStringToFile%28java.io.File,java.lang.String,java.nio.charset.Charset,boolean%29) I used to determine this. Eventually `writeStringToFile` is called when you call write.

This makes sense as its a static method which returns nothing.

So, it doesn't buffer data internally. Every time you call `write` data will be written to the file.

Comment: no problem! We all need someone to get us going the right direction again from time to time.

Comment: I am using FileUtils.write(..) for some specific logging into files, its quite multithreaded scenario. In Linux i get into problems after some time with IOException(Too many files open). I increased FileDescriptors limit and for now it seems to be running fine, but I am little bit curious if something its not hanging in memory.